# Airflow with Vault as backend secret

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, backend, kubernetes-helm, vault

Its my first question here!
I really need help, I have been trying this over a week and it's not working :(

I created airflow with helm on openshift (kubernetes).
I use CeleryKubernetesExecutor
I use a costume CA - i put it also on the pod (edit the image with new dockerfile)

in my values file:

```
secrets_backend_kwargs:
  url: "https://my_vault"
  variables_path: "variables"
  conecctions_path: "connections"
  auth_type: "token"
  config_path: "config"
  mount point: 'my_mount_point/'
  token: "my_token"
  verify: "path_to_vault_ca_cert"

config:
  secrets:
    backend: "airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend"
    backend_kwargs: '{{ .Values.secrets_backend_kwargs | toJson }}
```

in my airflow.cfg its look like:

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend
backend_kwargs = {"auth_type": "token", "conecctions_path": "connections", "config_path": "config", "mount_point": "my_mount_point/", "token": "my_token","url": "https://my_vault", "variables_path": "variables", "verify": "path_to_vault_ca_cert"}
```

in my vault:
example to variable:
[my vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFFBr.jpg)
I cant see the variable not in airflow ui and not in the pod (command: airflow variables list)

I try to make errors to see some logs -
if there is an error in the "backend" var, I saw it in the "wait-for-airflow-migratios" pod (job) that its not working.
but when I make an error for example in the "backend_kwargs" there are no logs! he is complete the job (connect to the DB) and move on.
I don't see ant logs in the scheduler / webserver / worker

I also tried with verify: false in the backend_kwargs var (doesnt change anything)
I tried to look for logs, but its seems like he is not trying to connect to the vault, no error or anything

any ideas why?
why there are no logs or error , is there another configuration to make?

thanks for the help!! I would really appriciate it.